# how to store smarty variable output into php variable, to complete mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I want to run mysql query in smarty template file.......

file extension is .html

every thing running fine just i want to run a query that is incomplete able without smarty variable

for example
$q1 = mysql_query("select *from class_users where id={$v.user_id}");  Not working

i want to store {$v.user_id} into a php variable e.g $var="{$v.user_id}";

```
    <?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","***","****") or die('error connecting: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("****") or die('error selecting db: ' . mysql_error()); //select database  
?>

<div class="classified{if $v.highlited && $ads_settings.enable_highlited} highlited{/if} {if $v.featured && $ads_settings.enable_featured} featured{/if}" {if $v.highlited && $ads_settings.enable_highlited}style='background: {$ads_settings.highlited_color};'{/if}>

{if $v.featured && $ads_settings.enable_featured}<div class="featured-icon"></div>{/if}

{capture name=some_content assign=details_url}
{if $seo_settings.enable_mod_rewrite}{seo->makeDetailsLink p1=`$v.id` p2=`$v.title`}{else}{$live_site}/details.php?id={$v.id}{/if}
{/capture}
<div style="margin-left: {$ads_settings.thmb_width+10}px;"> 
<div>
      <div class="classified_photo" style="width: {$ads_settings.thmb_width+10}px; margin-left: -{$ads_settings.thmb_width+10}px;">
    <a href="{$details_url}" name="listing{$v.id}">
    <img src="{$live_site}/{$v.image}" class="pic" id="pic{$v.id}" onmouseover="this.className='pic_over'" onmouseout="this.className='pic'" alt="{if $v.image_id}{$v.title|strip_tags:false|substr:0:100}{/if}" />
    </a>
    {if $v.rented && $ads_settings.enable_rented}<div class="rented" id="rented{$v.id}" style="display: none;"></div>{elseif $v.sold && $ads_settings.enable_sold}<div class="sold" id="sold{$v.id}" style="display: none;"></div>{/if}
      </div>

      <div class="classified_content">
<h3><a href="{$details_url}" id="title{$v.id}">{$v.title|wordwrap:70:" ":true}</a></h3>
{if $data_set=="cars"}<div class="listing_make">{$v.make} {$v.model}</div>{/if}
{if $ads_settings.enable_price && $v.price>=0}<span class="price">{$v.price_curr}&nbsp;</span>{/if}
{if $v.location_str}<span class="location">{if $v.location_str && $ads_settings.enable_price && $v.price>=0} | {/if}{$v.location_str}</span>{/if}{if $v.location_str || ($ads_settings.enable_price && $v.price>=0)}<br/>{/if}
<div class="small">{if $ads_settings.show_ad_date_for_everybody==1}{$lng.listings.added_on}&nbsp;{$v.date_nice}{else}{$lng.listings.posted}{/if}&nbsp;{$lng.general.to}&nbsp;<u>{$v.category}</u></div>
<p>{$v.description|truncate:200:"...":false|wordwrap:70:" ":true}</p>

<span class="classified_links">

{* if listings_compare *}
{if in_array("listings_compare", $modules_array)}

<a href="javascript:;" class="addcmpwin" id="cmp{$v.id}" {if in_array($v.id, $cmp)}style="display: none;"{/if}>{$lng_compare.add_to_compare}</a>&nbsp;

<a href="javascript:;" class="remcmpwin" id="remcmp{$v.id}" {if !in_array($v.id, $cmp)}style="display: none;"{/if}>{$lng_compare.rem_compare}</a>&nbsp;

{/if}
{* end if listings_compare *}

<a href="javascript:;" class="fshare" id="fshare{$v.id}">{$lng.listings.recommend_this}</a>

&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" {if $self_noext=="favorites" || in_array($v.id, $fav_array)}style="display: none;"{/if} class="addtofav" id="fav{$v.id}">{$lng.listings.add_to_favourites}</a>
<a href="javascript:;" {if $self_noext!="favorites" && !in_array($v.id, $fav_array)}style="display: none;"{/if} class="remfav" id="remfav{$v.id}">{$lng.listings.remove_favourite}</a>

&nbsp;<a href="{$details_url}">{$lng.listings.details}</a>&nbsp;

{if ($logged_in || !$ads_settings.hide_contact_when_not_logged)  && (!$v.sold || !$ads_settings.hide_contact_when_sold) && (!$v.rented || !$ads_settings.hide_contact_when_rented)}&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" class="fmailto" id="mailto{$v.user_id}_{$v.id}">{$lng.general.contact}</a>{/if}
</span>

{if ($v.priority_name && $ads_settings.enable_priorities) || ($v.video && $v.enable_video && $ads_settings.enable_video)}
    <table class="extra" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    {if $v.priority_name && $ads_settings.enable_priorities}
    <td><div class="buttonwrapper"><div class="priority-left"><div class="priority-right">{$v.priority_name}</div></div></div></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    {/if}

    {if $v.video && $v.enable_video && $ads_settings.enable_video}
    <td><div class="buttonwrapper"><div class="video-left"><div class="video-right">{$lng.listings.short_video}</div></div></div></td>
    {/if}
    </tr>
    </table>
{/if}
<div>
**<?php


$q1=mysql_query("select * from class_users where id={$v.user_id}");


while ($ev= mysql_fetch_object($q1)){
$did = "$ev->id";
$dname = "$ev->contact_name";
$drating     = "$ev->rating";
$rating = round($drating);
$dnorating = "$ev->no_ratings";
$dphoto  = "$ev->photo";
$dc  = "$ev->company_name";
$store_banner    = "$ev->store_banner";
$durl = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z\d\s-]+~u', '',  strtolower($dname));
$durl = str_replace(" ", "-", $durl);
$durls = "http://dealerspk.com/$did-$durl/store.html";
$dname = substr($dname, 0, 25);
$dcompany = substr($dc, 0, 30);
if ($photo){
$pict = "http://tatabata.com/uploads/photo/$photo";
}else{
$pict = "http://dealerspk.com/images/noimage.jpg";
}
}
?>**
</div>
    </div><!-- end: classified_content -->
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to run logic inside your template file? Isn't it Smarty's purpose to get rid of logic (except the conditional and loop statements) between the HTML lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `{php}` tags to [embed PHP code](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl) in your Smarty templates. Please note that this is a **deprecated** feature, though (see link) and might be removed from future versions. It also undermines the actual purpose of Smarty as a templating language that aims at separating presentation from application logic.

That being said, if you still want to do this, the following might work (untested, though):

```
{php}
$v = $this->getVariable('v');
print_r($v['user_id']);
{/php}
```

Answer (score 0):

$v is probably set from the PHP code that renders the template
use your database queries in the PHP files not in the template files
they are TEMPLATE files in the end !